# Angular2 service call json path not found

Tags: angular2-services

product.service.ts file :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    private _producturl='src/products.json';
    constructor(private _http: Http){}

   getproducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
   return this._http.get(this._producturl)
  .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
  .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
   }
  }
```

Please find the attached screenshot below for folder structure

but when the page loads it shows me an error :
zone.js:2744 GET http://0.0.0.0:4200/src/products.json 404 (Not Found)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNg07.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your `json` file in assets folder, and access from there like this

```
export class ProductService {
    private _producturl='./assets/products.json';
    constructor(private _http: Http){}
    .........
}
```

If you using Angular Cli you need to Keep the json file inside Assets folder (parallel to app dir) directory as per official docs.